# IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied while opening a file in Python

Tags: python, windows, file-io, ioerror

I was trying to access a PDF file on Python and I get this message:

```
IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'C.pdf'
```

Here is a piece of code:

```
fPDF = open(self.filename, 'ab+')
```

This is the code which opens the file
I have a Windows 64-bit PC with Python 2.7.9 installed

Comment: I am the administrator

Comment: Fore future readers - file might be read only or locked by another process

Answer (score 0):

The error is pretty self-describing, the user that runs the python script does not have to rights to open the file.

Try running your app as administrator.

Comment: It does not mean that you give the rights to the app. Open a console in admin mode and try again.

Comment: The console is in admin mode

Comment: Does the file already exists? Please add and ls -R of the path